# Need to figure our what a specific symbol is replaced to after macro expansion

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Can I view my compiler error in the pre-processed file? I am trying to figure out what a specific symbol is being replaced by after macro expansion. I am using Visual C++. Basically I would like to see the exact error causing line *in* the pre-processed file.

Comment: The other questions answers how I can get the pre-processed output. I know how to do that. What I am trying to do is as follows - (1.)My compiler has a problem with abc.cpp at line 233 (2) I would like to see the erroneous line(like 233 of abc.cpp) after pre-processing, see exactly what is not compilable after pre-processing, which basically means I want to see the error *in* the pre-processed file. the exact line that is causing the error

Comment: Ok, would help if you actually made that clear in the question. "I am trying to figure out what a specific symbol is being replaced by after macro expansion" does not convey that and is answered by the linked question. Please update the question with more detail and I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Sure, i will do that. Thanks  @kaylum!

Comment: I have reworded the question, can you please vote to reopen the question @kalyum

Comment: I have. But it takes a number of votes to reopen.